# Is my Python application that will request data from multiple API endpoints simultaneously correct?

Tags: python, api, csv, url, request

> We expect you to develop a small Python application which will request data from multiple API
> endpoints concurrently and save the data received from each endpoint in a separate CSV file.
> The API which will be used for this purpose is located at:
> https://fakestoreapi.com
> Request #1 will get all products from the relevant API endpoint (GET /products).
> Request #2 will get all users from the relevant API endpoint (GET /users).
> Received data will be saved in products.csv and users.csv files respectively.

Is my code correct?

```
import requests
import csv

# API endpoint URLs
products_url = "https://fakestoreapi.com/products"
users_url = "https://fakestoreapi.com/users"

# Send requests to API endpoints
products_response = requests.get(products_url)
users_response = requests.get(users_url)

# Check if requests are successful
if products_response.status_code != 200:
    print("Products request failed with status code:", products_response.status_code)
    exit()
    
if users_response.status_code != 200:
    print("Users request failed with status code:", users_response.status_code)
    exit()

# Save products data to CSV file
products_data = products_response.json()
with open("products.csv", "w", newline="") as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    writer.writerow(products_data[0].keys())
    for product in products_data:
        writer.writerow(product.values())

# Save users data to CSV file
users_data = users_response.json()
with open("users.csv", "w", newline="") as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    writer.writerow(users_data[0].keys())
    for user in users_data:
        writer.writerow(user.values())
```

Comment: Is there anything specific stopping you from running your code yourself?

Comment: Does it request data from the two endpoints simultaneously and save the result in two separate .csv files?

Comment: This will get the api result consecutively rather than concurrently

Comment: agreed, requirement is not met

Answer (score 0):

No, your code does not fit the requirements laid out. In your code, you run the following functions:

```py
products_response = requests.get(products_url)
users_response = requests.get(users_url)
```

However, the first call of `requests.get` will stop the second call from executing until it finishes. This means that your code is *synchronous*. What you're being asked for is *asynchronous* (or multithreaded) code that will run the two GET requests at the same time. You can accomplish this with the following code using the `threading` library, which you can integrate into your current code:

```py
import requests
import threading

url1_response = ""
url2_response = ""

def get_url1():
    global url1_response
    response = requests.get("https://example.com/endpoint1")
    url1_response = response.text
    print(f"Response from endpoint 1: {response.text[:35]}...")

def get_url2():
    global url2_response
    response = requests.get("https://example.com/endpoint2")
    url2_response = response.text
    print(f"Response from endpoint 2: {response.text[:35]}...")

# Create threads for each URL
threads = []
thread = threading.Thread(target=get_url1)
threads.append(thread)
thread2 = threading.Thread(target=get_url2)
threads.append(thread2)

# Start threads
for thread in threads:
    thread.start()

print("Waiting for threads to finish...")
for thread in threads:
    thread.join()

# Process the data here
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how you would concurrently do this. But I think you could use multiprocessing, even though it is extreme overkill for this simple task.

This is how my solution looks:

```py
import requests
import csv
from multiprocessing import Pool

# API endpoint URLs
products_url = "https://fakestoreapi.com/products"
users_url = "https://fakestoreapi.com/users"

def get_data(inp: tuple):
    url = inp[0]
    f_name = inp[1]

    r = requests.get(url)

    # Check if requests are successful
    if r.status_code != 200:
        print("Products request failed with status code:", r.status_code)
        return
    
    # Save products data to CSV file
    data = r.json()
    with open(f"{f_name}.csv", "w", newline="") as csvfile:
        writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
        writer.writerow(data[0].keys())
        for d in data:
            writer.writerow(d.values())
    
    return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    info = [(products_url, 'products',), (users_url, 'users',)]

    with Pool(2) as p: # 2 for 2 processes
        p.map(get_data, info)
```